# How to let Xcode know which asset to use for the target iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, autolayout

I am designing an app for **iOS** in **SWIFT**. I have decided that the auto layout will be compact and will be only for **iPhone in portrait mode**. I wanted to clear up a few hiccups on designing buttons for the **2** different **screen ratios**: the **first being the iPhone 4s** and the **second ratio being the iPhone 5 and above**. Because the new iPhones have a taller height, does that mean I will need to **design 2 different ratios of buttons**, and if so, **how do I use them in Xcode?** For example here's the stock apple calculator;

link to picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLW76.jpg

As you can see the the **buttons on the taller iPhone have a square shape.** The **buttons on the 4s are more stubby**. **What do I need to do in Xcode to let the app know which asset to use for the respective phone** and how would I implement that in Auto Layout?
thanks

Comment: You would be better off looking up an autolayout tutorial and working your way through that (Too much for a stack answer). If you have already, then you should let us know what you have done so far and be more specific about the issues you are having. As for assets, Xcode handles selecting the correct ones for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you setup autolayout constraints. This will make the buttons change shape/size depending on the device. You do not need to have multiple assets because all the phones you are talking about have the same retina (2x) display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add three different sized images for a single Image Set in Images.xcassets . The sizes should be 1x for iPhone 4s, 2x for iPhone 6(It'll work for iPhone 5 too) and 3x for iPhone 6 plus.[image: This is a example how it'll look like]